# How to program a related search

Tags: java, android, full-text-search

I have just coded a program on Android that can receive String input of title to change `uri` to retrieve various information on movies. However, the problem with the search right now is that I have to get the name exactly right in order to get a hit obviously because I am forming a `url` address based on the String input.

Is there anyway to create a program where I can program it a little differently so that my program does not require to receive the exact title of the movie in order to find the movies?

Say for example when you search "x-men", I am able to get the movie but if I type "xman" or "xmen" or anything a little different, I am unable to retrieve any information.

Also, is there any way to program a `related search` so that when I find x-men I won't just get the first series but all the related series? It would be great if you guys could at least point me at the right direction to look answers for.

Comment: Are you using a SQLite database on your device or an API like IMDB to do this?

Comment: I'm using API @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

Its more complex than you think. Here are some rough idea how can you do it.

1. You need your own dictionary so that you can perform the search. That dictionary would consist of all the movies that you know. (It can be further discussed to optimize)
2. You build a tree (binary tree) and traverse through the tree as the user input a character. Ofcourse, this tree will only accept alphabets so you would ignore any symbol
3. At any given point, the subtree of the tree could give you all possible movies "if" spelled correctly
4. If no spelled correctly, say user type in Ter and then 'r' (for terminator). so your tree will tell you that "expected" next letter should have been 'm' but its 'r' - assuming there is only 1 node in the tree after 'r' and that is m.

Comment: hmm what area of computer science is related to learning this kind of work?

Comment: Is that the things like SQLite?

Comment: you can use `LIKE` clause in your search if you are using a DB layer underneath. Perhaps you would need a for loop to use the `LIKE` clause by making a permutations of `wildcard` strings.

Comment: hmm okay I guess I'm not up for this task yet I'm a newbie and have no idea what you are talking about. But thanks I'll look into `LIKE` and `wildcard`

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to take a stab at this question. You mention that you don't have an underlying DB.

Not a problem. Given that you have the movie names, one approach could be a prefix tree kind of approach. Wherein, as soon as the user types 'X', all titles starting with 'X' are shown. This functionality would be very similar to what you see on Google, or YouTube, or Netflix. 
You can, obviously, put more/fewer constraints on the construction of the `Trie` to shape it however you please. Why Trie vs Array? Tries are faster. Read on to find out more.

Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on Tries. An implementation of a [Trie ADT in Java](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/blob/master/leetcode/Trie.java). An implementation of a [T9 dictionary (like the good old days) in C](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/tree/master/T9%20Trie).

Comment: wow this is very cool I'll definitely look into these. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jchoi Not a problem. Let me know if you have any questions.